# Error when trying to use variables in the post build event with delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, batch-file, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I use windows 7 pro service pack 1.

I have the following code in the post build event :

```
SET VAR1=BLABLA
ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt
```

It wont work. In the file, i get «command echo activated» (translated from french).

Embarcadero documentation says that i can use any valid dos command in those events.

If i just use :

```
ECHO BLABLA > Test.txt
```

It works, no problem. Is this a bug or there is a problem with % character ? % is an ascii char so i dont even know what could be the problem.

ty for your help.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you have that code directly in the post-build event in the project options. Put the code instead in a batch file and call it from your post-build event, e.g. `call mypostbuildevent.cmd`.

Comment: Whilst they can be any valid DOS command, I expect they're each executed in their own environment, thus the variable SET in the first is not known in the second, so I'd follow Ondrej's suggestion

Comment: yep i did test using a .cmd file with parameters and it works. I did also put the two commands on the same line with the & and i didnt work either. set VAR1=BLABLA & echo %VAR1% > Test.txt.

Comment: can anyone test it in his own delphi 10.2 ? i d like to know if it s just on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is used in `cmd` to delimit variablenames when the *value* of the variable is required, hence `echo %var1% > test.txt` will write the current value of the environment variable `var1` to the file.

If `var1` is not defined at the time, it will report the `echo` status (Echo is on/off`.

This can be circumvented by using `echo(%var1%` - the `(` modifies `echo`'s behaviour to *not* report the `echo` status if the arguments are resolved to *nothing*.

If you want to `echo` a literal `%` then you need to escape the `%` with another `%`. `cmd` normally uses `^` to escape symbols with a special meaning - `%` is the exception; `%%` to echo a literal `%`.

BTW - the space between the `string to be echoed` and the redirector **will** be output to the file. To prevent this, use `> test.txt echo %var1%` Note that `>` creates a file anew. `>>` will create or append if the file already exists. The space between the redirector and the filename is optional.

However, it's important when using batch to post **exactly** the code that's in use.

```
SET VAR1=BLABLA
ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt
```

will work happily.

```
SET VAR1 = BLABLA
ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt
```

will not because this latter code sets a variable named "var1<kbd>Space</kbd>"

---

On my 10.2.1 system, I've tried the code as published.

The *actual* code that's executed is

```
SET VAR1=BLABLA&ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt
```

not

```
SET VAR1=BLABLA
ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt
```

as shown in the "Build events commands" window.

This will not work *because* the entire line is executed as published on the "build events" page - `SET VAR1=BLABLA&ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt` which will be interpreted by `cmd` after `cmd` performs its standard parsing routine.

`cmd` replaces any `%var%` with the actual value **at parse time**, not at **run time** hence as `var1` has no value when the line `SET VAR1=BLABLA&ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt` is *parsed*, the code is *executed* as `SET VAR1=BLABLA&ECHO  > Test.txt` hence the problem encountered.

To cure this, you need to use

```
SET VAR1=BLABLA&call ECHO %%VAR1%% > Test.txt
```

where `cmd` will execute the parsed-`ECHO` command in a subshell. `%` is the escape character for `%` so the subshell executes `ECHO %VAR1% > Test.txt` *after* `var1` has been set.

I'd suggest you raise this as a problem with EMBT. Batch commands cannot be strung together with `&` without side-effects. The code entered into the "Build events commands" window should be executed without reformatting - just written to a (temporary) batch file and the batch file then executed.

No doubt the eager downvoters will support the resolution of this problem.

Comment: The code used for executing this is `<Exec Command="$(PostBuildEvent)"` located in CodeGear.Common.Targets, which actually is capable of executing multi line commands. I guess, the problem is to have these multi line commands stored consistently in the dproj file.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have suspected that. I am too unfamiliar with batch.